# Fetching data from the server using Vue.js and Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a `Vue` app that successfully makes an ajax request to fetch data from the server. I am then looping through the data using a `v-for` like so:

```
<div v-for="post in posted">
     <img :src="'{{Config::get('app.url')}}/sudan2018book/public/img/' + post.user.pic">
</div>
```

But I am receiving the following errors and am not sure what they mean:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means `post.user` is null. That's probably because you are either making an `async` call that hasn't retrieved the data at that point, or, some of your posts have a `user` property that is set to null. Either way, you should check in your `v-for` that `post.user` is not `null` before trying to access the property, which you can do using a `v-if`:

```
<div v-for="post in posted">
     <img :src="'{{Config::get('app.url')}}/sudan2018book/public/img/' + post.user.pic" v-if="!!post.user">
</div>
```

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ofm4fe60/